# Get a table with one row per id and multiple columns from a table with multiple rows for same id and calculate sum based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my commissions table where some ids have two entries and others only one. If there is a reverse entry within 30 days from the original commission date the original commission should be reversed, but if the reverse entry is after 30 days it should be ignored.

| lead_id | commission_date | commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22940 | 01/03/2020 | 30 |
| 22940 | 30/03/2020 | -30 |
| 22941 | 30/04/2020 | 30 |
| 22942 | 31/03/2020 | 60 |
| 22942 | 15/06/2020 | -60 |

Therefore this is the final table I want to get to.

| lead_id | total commission |
| --- | --- |
| 22940 | 0 |
| 22941 | 30 |
| 22942 | 60 |

The code I have written for the first part of the query, should produce jut one row for any lead_id storing both commission dates and commission amounts if present (some ids only have one entry and no reverse commission). Here is the code

```
WITH TAB_RN AS
(
      SELECT commissions.lead_id, commissions.commission_date, commissions.commission_amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY commissions.lead_id, commissions.commission_date) AS RN
  FROM commissions
)
SELECT T1.lead_id, 
       T1.commission_date AS DATE1, T1.commission_amount AS amount1
       T2.commission_date AS DATE2, T2.commission_amount AS amount2
FROM TAB_RN T1
LEFT JOIN TAB_RN T2 ON T1.lead_id = T2.lead_id AND T1.commission_date = T2.commission_date AND T2.RN = 2
WHERE T1.RN = 1
```

it should produce this result

| lead_id | date 1 | amount1 | date 2 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22940 | 01/03/2020 | 30 | 30/03/2020 | -30 |
| 22941 | 30/04/2020 | 30 |  |  |
| 22942 | 31/03/2020 | 60 | 15/06/2020 | -60 |

but instead I'm returned

| lead_id | date 1 | amount1 | date 2 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22940 | 01/03/2020 | 30 |  |  |
| 22940 | 30/03/2020 | -30 |  |  |
| 22941 | 30/04/2020 | 30 |  |  |
| 22942 | 31/03/2020 | 60 |  |  |
| 22942 | 15/06/2020 | -60 |  |  |

I then want to calculate the difference between date 1 and 2 and if the difference is less than 30 days sum amount 1 and amount2, otherwise only amount1 should be counted.

Finally I want to join the table with the companies table on commissions.company = companies.id and filter by company x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break it down

Select for commissions

```
select lead_id, commission_date, commission
from commissions
where commission > 0
```

Then join this to valid returned commissions

```
select commissions.lead_id, commissions.commission_date, commissions.commission + ret.commission as commission_total
from commissions
join (
  -- returned commissions have negative value.
  select lead_id, commission_date, commission
  from commissions
   where commsion < 0
) ret on commissions.lead_id = ret.ldead_id
       and   commissions.commission= ret.commission * -1
       and datediff(day,ret.commission_date,comm commissions.commission_date) <=30
where commission > 0
```

Comment: thanks! I modified it slightly and it works!